# How to read Data from XML for 3rd Party Application?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I want to read the data from the following website:

http://www.espncricinfo.com/commonwealth-bank-series-2012/engine/current/match/518956.html

I have attached an image the details, from which I wish to read the data:
[image]

Can You please help me in getting the details as mentioned above?

And also let me know how the data is supposed to be extracted every time when required.
I will be using this XML data in VB10. This will simply allow me to create a widget that will show me the cricket score update that frequently.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't XML but HTML.  Can't you just screen-scrape the data.  In other words, download the page and use regular expressions to locate and extract the data from the webpage source?

Comment: Will i be able to extract the data when the file changes?

Comment: You'll have to regularly fetch the page. There isn't an automated way to let your application know when the data on the page changes (thats the nature of HTTP), so you will have to keep fetching the page over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), but don't use it to steal any data :)